# ajax didnt work inside form tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

my ajax code is working well when there is no  tag.. but i need the form tag what shall i do?.. here is my code..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function injury_nature(){
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"ajax_details.php",
         data:{
             allvals:$("#nature_id").val(),
             },
         success:function(msg){
             $("#div").html(msg);
             }});
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<table border="2">
<tr><th colspan="2">Injury Details</th></tr>
<tr><td>
<select id="nature_id" name="injury_nature" onChange="injury_nature()">
<option><--select--></option>
<option value="1">Musculoskeletal Injuries</option>
<option value="2">Soft Tissue Injuries</option>
<option value="3">Illnesses</option>
<option value="4">Other Injuries</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><div id="div"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

when there is a form tag i get this error:

```
TypeError: injury_nature is not a function
injury_nature()
```

Please help me thank you so much.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: why are you working with such an ancient version of jQuery? Current versions are 1.10.2 or 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a element with the same name `injury_nature` as the function.

just rename the function to `injury_nature_change` and it will be fine

```
<select id="nature_id" name="injury_nature" onChange="injury_nature_change()">
```

then

```
function injury_nature_change(){
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"ajax_details.php",
         data:{
             allvals:$("#nature_id").val(),
             },
         success:function(msg){
             $("#div").html(msg);
             }});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your using jquery why don't you just use the `change` function?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nature_id").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"ajax_details.php",
         data:{
             allvals:$("#nature_id").val(),
             },
         success:function(msg){
             $("#div").html(msg);
             }});
    });
});
</script>
```

then just remove the `onchange` on select tag

```
<select id="nature_id" name="injury_nature" >
```